# CSS, how to align two div between two div like a hamburger?

Tags: html, css

How to make left and right area sitting between top and bottom area aligned ? It appears they doesn't aligned although having the same height. Note that left and right divs don't have text of same length. Could anyone help pls.

html

```
  <div id="top_area"></div>
    <div class="left_area">I'm left area, which has longer text</div>
    <div class="right_area">right area</div>
    <div  id="bottom_area"></div>
```

css

```
<style>
#top_area{
    width:550px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.left_area{
     box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffcc99;
    width:140px;
    height:80px;
    padding-top:30px;

}
.right_area{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffcc99;
    width:140px;
    height:80px;
    padding-top:30px;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

#bottom_area{
    min-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
 background-color: orange;
  width: 550px;
  border-radius:5px;
  display: block !important;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you're needs correctly, you need to `float` the `.left-area` and `.right-area` `div` elements.

In order to do that and not drive yourself crazy, you should first add a *wrapper* `div` around all of the content and set it to the maximum width you want for your content:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="top_area"></div>
    <div class="left_area">I'm left area, which has longer text</div>
    <div class="right_area">right area</div>
    <div  id="bottom_area"></div>
</div>
```

Then, and this will make things easier for you in the long run, change the width unit for the inner elements to `%` rather than `px`:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 550px;
  height: auto;
}

.left_area{
    width:50%;
    height:80px;

}
.right_area{

    width: 50%;
    height: 80px;

}
```

Now we have that in place, lets get your centre divs to sit next to each other (if thats not what you want please update your answer and I will update this)

We can do that by `float`ing them both `left`, and (for now) removing any `margin`s 
**CSS:**

```
.left_area{
     box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffcc99;
    width:50%;
    height:80px;
    padding-top:30px;
  float: left;

}
.right_area{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    height:80px;
   padding-top:30px;
   /* margin-left: 15%;*/
  float: left;
}
```

Then to stop them sitting on top of the bottom "bun" add a `clear: both;` to the `#bottom_area` element. I also added `boz-sizing: border-box` to ensure it is the same width as the top "bun". `border-box` ensures that `padding` and `margin` does not increase the element's overall width.

**CSS:**

```
#bottom_area{
  min-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 550px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block !important;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  /* Add the styles below */
  clear: both;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is a working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYZOgN)